# incorrect return value from a function

Tags: c++

I've attempted to learn functions with simple solutions and in this solution I want the user to input any number and output to them if what they entered is a decimal digit, in the code below I've attempted that, by iterating through numbers 0-9 and if the input matches one of these numbers the return value is true, however this isn't the case, any number input returns false and if a char value is input the return value is true.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int is_digit(int digit);
int main()
{
    cout << "Enter a character and the program will tell you if it is a decimal digit: ";
    
    int input;
    cin >> input;
    
    if (is_digit(input))
    {
        cout << "The character entered is a decimal digit!";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "The character is not a decimal digit!";
    }
}

int is_digit(int digit)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (digit == i)
        {
            return(true);
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            return(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should not return `false` until you check all ten digits.

Comment: Refer to [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems).

Comment: This is an excellent time to [learn how to run your code in a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173).  It's a vital skill, even for beginners, and would quickly reveal the cause of problems like yours.

Comment: A simpler approach would be `if (0 <= digit && digit <= 9) return true; else return false;`. Even simpler: `return 0 <= digit && digit <= 9;`.

Comment: Remember that once the execution hits a `return` the function is done. It will not continue after the return.

Comment: You are at a point where you should learn about debugging. You want to read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert.

Basically you set a breakpoint at the start of your program and then follow the code execution line by line. You will be able to see the variable contents and cross check after each line whether your program is doing what you expect it should do.

Comment: With all of this said an `int` can only be an `int`

Comment: @PeteBecker: whether that is simpler depends on whether you know how `&&` works. Also, for a lot of beginners it's a hurle to go from `if (x) return true; else return false;` to `return x;`. I see that with every of my students. But it is something I will teach them early.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help and comments, I'll be taking the time to go and learn about how to use a debugger before continuing with practicing functions.

Answer (score 1):

Every path through your `is_digit` function exits on the first iteration of your loop. You need to remove the `else` branch from inside the loop, and terminate the entire function with a single `return false`.

Otherwise, your program enters the loop, and tests `digit` against `i`. If they are equal, the function returns `true`, which is desired behavior. But, if they are *not* equal, your function returns `false` immediately, and no further comparisons are done against 1..9.

---

It's also worth noting that your entire function should be replaced with a single statement: `return i >= 0 && i <= 9`. Not only is there no need for a loop here, it's *extremely* inefficient to implement this as a loop.

Answer (score 1):

You're exiting your function too early.

```cpp
int is_digit(int digit) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (digit == i)
        {
            return(true);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Here is an example.

First loop : `i = 0, digit = 9`

```cpp
if (digit == i) { // 9 == 0 which is false, we jump to esle
    ....
} 

else { // We are here
    return false; // We immediately return false without checking other values
}
```

Also, you can just do

```cpp
int is_digit(int digit) {
    return (digit >= 0 && digit < 10) // && is the AND operator
}
```